# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method file on channel video_thumbnail)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using [`video_thumbnail 0.2.4`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) package to get thumbnail form video url. If I uploaded video from android device then its working perfect but If I used iPhone device, Always get the error

> `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method file on channel video_thumbnail)`

I'm using `Firestore` as backend and using `Firebase Storage` for store my video/photos. Below are my code. Url is correct and video playing in the browser.

```
Future<String> thumbnailImageFromVideoUrl(String url, String feedID) async {
    try {
      String filePath = _strDirectoryPath + "/" + feedID + '.png';
      print("filePath -- $filePath");
      print("videoURL -- $url");
      return await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
        video: url,
        thumbnailPath: filePath,
        imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
        maxHeight: 240,
        quality: 50,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Video Thumbnail Error: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Kindly help me on this case.

Comment: did you check if the file path is accesible in IOS and have permissions to access he images and save images, had a smiliar problem with images where IOS needed a diffrent save directory than android because of security in the background

Comment: Yes, previously working perfectly and also I checked same url with android device too. same issue with android device too.

Comment: shot in the dark, can't test myself but I see the thumnail has no maxwidth assigned to it, I know it should scale according to aspect ratio or the original image but I would try adding a hardcoded value for the width seeing as you already have height

Comment: also would suggest trying a diffrent image format

Comment: @RubenMeiring Yep right you can't test but really thank you for supporting me. I have tried all the stuff like changed image formate type, changed height/width and `filePath` too but can't get success.

Comment: I have the same problem here

Comment: is this issue solved?

Comment: Facing the same issue for v0.5.3 https://github.com/justsoft/video_thumbnail/issues/133

Answer (score 0):

I've been working using `video_thumbnail 0.4.3` ([Video Thumbnail](https://github.com/justsoft/video_thumbnail/issues/96)) and I found that due to some video formats this kind of error is generated by SDK.
There is no solution till now however you can control it by the `try:catch` function.

Also i have created the issue on there GitHub repository with this [link of issue i've created](https://github.com/justsoft/video_thumbnail/issues/96).

Comment: Reinstalling the app did it for me

Comment: Dear @Taio, that issue has been fixed in its new version.

Answer (score 0):

The same error has been resolved after I updated the plugin video_thumbnail: ^0.4.3 to video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code for your flutter application, then closing & restarting the editor & hence the application may help detect the newly added dependency in your application.
This happened to me several times & the solution above worked well for me.
Hope it helps, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. Restart the application works for me.

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method data on channel plugins.justsoft.xyz/video_thumbnail)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, detach the app from debug (Stop the app if running)

Go to the project directory and run these below-mentioned commands one-by-one:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Then, try running the project.